# How to achieve Batch Inserts with Spring data and SQLite?

Tags: java, spring, sqlite, hibernate, jpa

I am trying to perform **Batch Insert** with spring data jpa and *Hibernate* but the problem is *Hibernate* only supports batch inserts when the generated value strategy is `SEQUENCE` but somehow sqlite does not support this strategy so I resort to Identity which works fine but does not support batching with hibernate. Is there any solution or workaround for this.

###### Entity

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "party")
public class PartyEntity implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "party_id", nullable = false)
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "party_name", unique = true)
    @NonNull
    private String name;

    @Column(name = "party_phone_number", unique = true)
    private Long number;

}
```

SQLite do have this table called 'sqlite_sequence' which I try to use with @SequenceGenerator but hibernate tries to create this table which we cannot as this is a reserved table. And same goes for @TableGenerator.

###### Annotation for sequence used

```
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "party_seq")
@SequenceGenerator(name = "party_seq", sequenceName = "sqlite_sequence", allocationSize = 1)
```

###### Annotation for table used

```
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.TABLE, generator = "sqlite_generator")
@TableGenerator(name = "sqlite_generator", table = "sqlite_sequence", pkColumnName = "name",
            valueColumnName = "seq", pkColumnValue = "party", initialValue = 1, allocationSize = 1)
```

DDL script for the table

```
CREATE TABLE party (
    party_id              INTEGER       PRIMARY KEY ASC AUTOINCREMENT,
    party_name            VARCHAR (256) UNIQUE
                                        NOT NULL,
    party_phone_number    INTEGER (10)  UNIQUE
);
```